# Proving a second order special limit without derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The special limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}=\frac 1 2
$$
can be proved by Taylor expansion or with L'Hôpital's rule. Is it possoble to prove it without using derivatives?

Comment: Is there a reason that neither of these methods can be used?

Comment: If we *define* $e^x$ as $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ that is trivial.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\int_{0}^{1}(1-y)e^{xy}\,dy $$
hence by the dominated convergence theorem
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\int_{0}^{1}(1-y)\,dy = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have by $x=2y$

$$\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}=\frac{e^{2y}-2y-1}{4y^2}=\frac{(e^y-1)^2+2e^y-2y-2}{4y^2}=\frac14\left(\frac{e^y-1}{y}\right)^2+\frac12\frac{e^y-y-1}{y^2}$$

therefore assuming that the limit exists we have

$$L=\frac14+\frac12L \implies L=\frac12$$

Refer also to

- [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/387333/505767)

Comment: Since L'Hôpital and Taylor expansion are explicitly ruled out, you might want to  mention how $(e^y-1)/y \to 1$ is obtained.

Comment: @MartinR My interpretation is that we can't use l'Hopital and Taylor to solve the limit but I think we can use the well known standard limit which, as you can know I suppose, can be derived without Hopital and Taylor. I'll add a reference to that anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=e^{\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{x}$$

Then your limit is

$$\lim_{X\to0^+}\frac{f(X)-f(0)}{X-0}$$

Comment: In the limit expression, you mean $f(x^2)$.

Comment: @AnuragA No. {}{}{}{}{}{}.

Comment: is that by derivative?